# Fetch unique friend relationship in a two way relations table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following db structure for my friendship table:

```
friends
-------
id | user_id | friend_id | action
 1      25         32       done
 2      32         25       done
 3      85         50       done
 4      50         85      not now
 5      18         52       done
```

I have got this maintenance project which uses the above structure for storing friendship. Following are the cases:

1. 25 and 32 are friends as they have the records (id 1, 2) and done in the action column
2. User 85 sent request to 50 (id: 3) but 50 did not accept with action 'not now'
3. User 52 did not take any action on request from user 18

- Now I want to get all the unique complete relations (when both users have taken action done) from the above structure. So, relationship between 25 and 32 should be shown only once.
- All users who have not responded to the requests or took an action `not now`.

As this is a maintenance project I cannot really change the structure so have to work around this.

Comment: Why did you write *"All users who have not responded to the requests or took an action not now."*? Do you want them too?

Answer (score 0):

You could join on two subqueries, one for each side of the relationship. To make sure you don't get duplicate answers, you can have one subquery handle `user_id`s smaller than the `friend_id`s and the other handle the other way round:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.fried_id
FROM   (SELECT user_id, friend_id
        FROM   friendship
        WHERE  user_id < friend_id AND status = 'done') u
JOIN   (SELECT user_id, friend_id
        FROM   friendship
        WHERE  user_id > friend_id AND status = 'done') f ON
       u.user_id = f.friend_id AND 
       u.friend_id = f.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all completed friendships, join the table to itself matching on the reverse relationship:

```
select a.user_id, a.friend_id
from friendships a
join friendships b on b.user_id = a.friend_id
  and b.friend_id = a.user_id
  and b.action = 'done'
where a.user_id < a.friend_id
and a.action = 'done'
```

The `where` clause ensures you only get each relationship once by selecting only rows where the user_id is less than the friend_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your first question:

```
 SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id, a.action
 FROM friends a
 INNER JOIN friends b ON a.friend_id = b.user_id
 WHERE a.action = 'done' AND b.action = 'done'
 AND a.user_id < b.user_id
```

--Second

```
 SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id, a.action
 FROM friends  a
 LEFT JOIN friends b ON a.friend_id = b.user_id
 WHERE a.action = 'done' 
 AND (b.action <> 'done' OR b.user_id IS NULL)
```